# C++ in a Windows Driver

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, driver

I'm writing a simple WDM driver, and I'd like to use a C++ class in it.

My problem is that I'm not sure which lib file should I link the compiled file to.
Linking to msvcrt creates dependency on *ntdll.dll*, which of course cannot be satisfied in Kernel-Mode. Without linking to msvcrt, there is no new/delete operators - and I get linkage errors.

How can I enable C++ features for my driver?

Comment: You should read this. http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/b/5/5b5bec17-ea71-4653-9539-204a672f11cf/KMcode.doc

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely read it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, implementing new/delete operators is enough for my problem (as long as I don't use exceptions and other C++ features).

So I implemented the operators in the following way, and now everything works:

```
#include <ntddk.h>

void *__cdecl operator new(size_t count) {
    return ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, count, 'TRCm');
}

void __cdecl operator delete(void *object) {
    ExFreePoolWithTag(object, 'TRCm');
}
```